# Reading pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, parquet

In databricks notebook, I am creating a source folder with year & month concatenated.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now() # current date and time

year = now.strftime("%Y")
month = now.strftime("%m")

df = '"' + 'abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/bronze/folder1/folder2/' + year + '/' + month + '/"'
print(df)
```

I get the result I am looking for in the print
**"abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/bronze/folder1/folder2/2023/07/"**

However when I try to read a dataframe from the destination through pyspark, I get an error message which I am not sure what is causing it. Appreciate you help in this. Thanks

```
DF = (
    spark
    .read
    .option("header", "true")
    .parquet(df)
    )
```

Error Message

IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in scheme name at index 0: "abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/bronze/folder1/folder2/2023/07/%22

Answer (score 1):

Flock,

It's unnecessary to add quotation marks when concatenating strings. If you remove the '"' at the beggining and at the ending of df, your code will work.

I suggest you use f-strings to concatenate. It is more readable and easy to use.

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now() # current date and time

year = now.strftime("%Y")
month = now.strftime("%m")
basepath = 'abfss://container@storageaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/bronze/folder1/folder2'

df = f'{basepath}/{year}/{month}/'
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander for the solution & recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

The path you're creating is invalid. The error you're getting says that the quotation mark at the beginning is wrong. Remove the quotation marks at the beginning and end to fix it.

Comment: Thank you user2704177, the solution works. appreciate your speedy comment.